# Flag/close as "not a specific problem"?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825175/track-the-first-click-and-second-click-on-radio-button), a low-effort question asking us to do their work for them, where the problem given is really a series of small problems: Build the web interface, detect the clicks, validate, etc, any one of which could be an acceptable (though basic) question, but which together amount to "please write my code for me." I'd like to flag it as too broad, but the problems are each small enough that a complete answer would probably not actually be too long for this format, however it would not work well because it would be better to answer all of the problems individually so that people who have those problems in other contexts can find the solutions. "Unclear what you're asking" doesn't work because the question is clear enough; it's just not a good fit for Q&A. Therefore I'm proposing adding a flag/close reason to say that a question does not boil down to a specific problem, and that the asker should do as much as they can and then ask about the specific points at which they have trouble.

Comment: Close > Off-topic > Other > "Not a specific problem or whatever”.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I suppose the question is how often this is useful. I feel this could be applied to a good number of unhelpful "please write my code for me" questions.

Answer (score 2):

"Unclear what they are asking" fits. Are they asking for the entire solution? Are they asking for help on pieces they have problems with, but merely did not show what they have already tried?

"Offtopic ... debugging" could be used as they have code that is not working but they have not show it or what they have tried. The possibility that they have not written any code is included here as Stackoverflow is about helping them with problems in their code, not providing all of it.

I am not sure that there is a "best" close reason for that question. Your suggestion of "Too broad" is also quite valid. We do not know whether they want detailed multi-paragraph answers on eachtopic, or whether they just wants some hints.

Comment: As written, it seems clear enough to me that they have not tried much and are asking for the entire solution.

Comment: @Saposhiente Maybe you are correct. There are numerous Q&A discussing close reasons and suggesting new ones. But the leaders of Stackoverflow seem reluctant to change the current ones. I think their argument is that the current reasons have evolved over time and they now work well as they have resolved problems with interpretation of other earlier attempts at close reasons.